# How to save REPL session?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Is it possible to save a REPL session in a file? Is there a minimum version of Scala requiered to do this? I remember having seen someone do it, but I can't fine it in :help or in the documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is possible as of Scala 2.11. 
Example usage:

```
scala> 1
res0: Int = 1

scala> 2
res1: Int = 2

scala> 3
res2: Int = 3

scala> :save xxx

scala> :load xxx
Loading xxx...
res3: Int = 1
res4: Int = 2
res5: Int = 3
```

You can `:reset` before a `:load` to get correct references to results:

```
scala> 1
res0: Int = 1

scala> res0 + 1
res1: Int = 2

scala> :save xxx
```

later that day...

```
scala> 7
res0: Int = 7

scala> :reset
Resetting interpreter state.
Forgetting this session history:

7

Forgetting all expression results and named terms: $intp

scala> :load xxx
Loading xxx...
res0: Int = 1
res1: Int = 2
```

Comment: In fairness to the OP, it *is* missing from `:help` in 2.10 :).

Comment: @som-snytt I compile my project for 2.10, not 2.11, would that compile to 2.11, or just use 2.11 for sbt itself? or do you mean this was added in 2.11?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have in addition of the native Scala REPL the shell-scripting project [**Ammonite**](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Ammonite), which does have a [Save/Loadd Session feature](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#Save/LoadSession):

> Apart from plain saves and loads, which simply discard everything after the most recent save, you can also provide a name to these functions.
>   That lets you stop working on a branch, go do something else for a while, and be able to come back later to continue where you left off:

```
@ val (x, y) = (1, 2)
x: Int = 1
y: Int = 2

@ sess.save("xy initialized")

@ val z = x + y
z: Int = 3

@ sess.save("first z")

@ sess.load("xy initialized")

@ val z = x - y
z: Int = -1
```