# grab scala REPL history (from sbt console)

Tags: scala

Is it possible to get a history listing of all recent commands entered on the scala repl? (running the repl inside `sbt console` if it matters). `:history` followed by the number of commands back to show works, but it would be nice being able to export this to a text file that can be worked into a scala source file.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104736/how-to-save-repl-session) doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What is your scala version? Also all my REPL input is logged to `/home/me/.scala_history/` by default.

Comment: sbt 0.13.5, project built against Scala 2.10.3. Under the sbt `console` command, `:save` does not seem to work. Yet, `~/.scala_history` has the sbt console history indeed! thanks! still wonder if it should work under sbt which would be a bit nicer...

Comment: yup. try `scala> :save xxx`

Answer (score 16):

This is a simple trick:

```
    scala> def history = scala.io.Source.fromFile(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.scala_history").foreach(print)
    scala> history
```

Answer (score 11):

In [Scala 2.11+](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/) there are new REPL commands to save output.  See here:
[How to save REPL session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104736/how-to-save-repl-session)

In earlier versions you can get REPL history here:
`less ~/.scala_history`