# Saving all results in Scala REPL

Tags: java, scala, serialization, read-eval-print-loop, snapshot

Is there an easy way to save all the values of variables in scala *REPL*?

There is *:save* command in *scala* but it just saves the history of commands and the next time we need to recalculate everything from scratch.

I know that I can manually **serialize/de-serialize** everything I'm interested in, but there are two main difficulties (also applicable to java):

1. It is hard to manually write serialize/de-serialize code for every defined (Serializeable) variable and it is not extensible for later use.
2. It is only possible to save Serializable objects. I know that saving (hibernating) an arbitrary object may results in problems (especially for objects working with external resources), but whether there would be a problem or not, depends on the state of the program. Sometimes the programmer is sure that in the current situation there would be no problem saving the variables. I think there should be a way for the programmer to take the responsibility of saving everything, even the objects not explicitly defined Serializable.

**I appreciate answers solving any of these problems.**

Comment: What is your use case ? In the sense that why you want to save the state of all the variables of the repl ?

Comment: I need something like Matlab save/load functions. In my research, I usually deal with things that are hard to compute. When trying to develop and test new ideas (in an Exploratory Programming way), it is really useful to be able to save the current state of your work in order to continue working on it later or just because you're afraid of messing up your current results. Currently I'm using Java for implementing well designed OO programs, and Matlab for developing my new ideas. Being able to do both of these things in a single environment will dramatically increase my productivity.

Comment: i think the 2nd answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104736/how-to-save-repl-session is what you're looking for?